# How to disable XXE in libxml2in C?

Tags: c, xml-parsing, libxml2, xxe

Requirement: When i pass the following request to my application,

1) How to do XML validation on such input xml which is risk

2) How to disable XXE in libxml2 i.e. should not parse the ENTITY field

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE foo [
<!ENTITY foo SYSTEM "file:///etc/issue">
]><TRANSACTION>
<FUNCTION_TYPE>LINE_ITEM</FUNCTION_TYPE>
<COMMAND>ADD</COMMAND>
<COUNTER>3</COUNTER>
<MAC>qof2EtycqT9YMcmOfKowpyXVbRpgM/7rncS3liK4JOs=</MAC>
<MAC_LABEL>P_206</MAC_LABEL>
<RUNNING_TAX_AMOUNT>0.00</RUNNING_TAX_AMOUNT>
<RUNNING_TRANS_AMOUNT>1.00</RUNNING_TRANS_AMOUNT>
<LINE_ITEMS>
<MERCHANDISE>
<LINE_ITEM_ID>1</LINE_ITEM_ID>
<DESCRIPTION>&foo;</DESCRIPTION>
<QUANTITY>1</QUANTITY>
<UNIT_PRICE>5.00</UNIT_PRICE>
<EXTENDED_PRICE>5.00</EXTENDED_PRICE>
</MERCHANDISE>
</LINE_ITEMS>
</TRANSACTION>
```

I understand starting with libxml2 version 2.9, XXE has been disabled by default. But we are using 2.7.7 version currently.

According to this link [XML_ENTITY_PROCESSING](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XML_External_Entity_%28XXE%29_Processing)

The Enum xmlParserOption should not have the following options defined in libxml2:

XML_PARSE_NOENT: Expands entities and substitutes them with replacement text
XML_PARSE_DTDLOAD: Load the external DTD

Till now i was using `xmlParseMemory` function to parse an XML in-memory block and build a tree. This function does not take any parameter to set the xmlParserOption.

Then i Changed to `xmlReadMemory` function which also does same thing as `xmlParseMemory` function but takes different parameters.

```
docPtr = xmlReadMemory(szXMLMsg, iLen, "noname.xml", NULL, XML_PARSE_RECOVER);
```

Still I observe that ENTITY field is getting parsed.
Could anyone help me? Please let me know if you need any more additional information.

Thank you for your time.

Regards

Praveen

Answer (score 3):

If you *don't* specify `XML_PARSE_NOENT`, the `ENTITY` declaration is still parsed but the entity won't be replaced. Also, the file `/etc/issue` won't be opened which you can verify with `strace`. So to protect from XXE, you simply don't pass the  `XML_PARSE_NOENT` parser option.

The name of the option is a bit misleading, `XML_PARSE_NOENT` means that no entity nodes should be created in the parsed document. Consequently every entity is expanded. A better name would be something like `XML_PARSE_EXPAND_ENTITIES`.

If you really want to make sure or you want to expand entities with fine-grained control over which URLs to load, you can install your own external entity loader using [`xmlSetExternalEntityLoader`](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-parser.html#xmlSetExternalEntityLoader). If your handler always returns NULL, you're on the safe side. But note that the external entity loader is used to load all kinds of external resources, so completely disabling it might break other stuff (XIncludes or XSLT stylesheets, for example).

**EDIT:** I have no idea why the entity is replaced in your case. Here's a test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <libxml/parser.h>
#include <libxml/tree.h>

static xmlNodePtr
find_node(xmlNodePtr parent, const char *name) {
    for (xmlNodePtr cur = parent->children; cur != NULL; cur = cur->next) {
        if (cur->type == XML_ELEMENT_NODE
            && xmlStrcmp(cur->name, (const xmlChar*)name) == 0
        ) {
            return cur;
        }
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "Element '%s' not found\n", name);
    abort();

    return NULL;
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv) {
    static const char buf[] =
        "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n"
        "<!DOCTYPE foo [\n"
        "<!ENTITY foo SYSTEM \"file:///etc/issue\">\n"
        "]><TRANSACTION>\n"
        "<FUNCTION_TYPE>LINE_ITEM</FUNCTION_TYPE>\n"
        "<COMMAND>ADD</COMMAND>\n"
        "<COUNTER>3</COUNTER>\n"
        "<MAC>qof2EtycqT9YMcmOfKowpyXVbRpgM/7rncS3liK4JOs=</MAC>\n"
        "<MAC_LABEL>P_206</MAC_LABEL>\n"
        "<RUNNING_TAX_AMOUNT>0.00</RUNNING_TAX_AMOUNT>\n"
        "<RUNNING_TRANS_AMOUNT>1.00</RUNNING_TRANS_AMOUNT>\n"
        "<LINE_ITEMS>\n"
        "<MERCHANDISE>\n"
        "<LINE_ITEM_ID>1</LINE_ITEM_ID>\n"
        "<DESCRIPTION>&foo;</DESCRIPTION>\n"
        "<QUANTITY>1</QUANTITY>\n"
        "<UNIT_PRICE>5.00</UNIT_PRICE>\n"
        "<EXTENDED_PRICE>5.00</EXTENDED_PRICE>\n"
        "</MERCHANDISE>\n"
        "</LINE_ITEMS>\n"
        "</TRANSACTION>\n";

    xmlDocPtr doc = xmlReadMemory(buf, sizeof(buf), "noname.xml", NULL,
                                  XML_PARSE_RECOVER);

    xmlNodePtr trans = find_node((xmlNodePtr)doc, "TRANSACTION");
    xmlNodePtr items = find_node(trans, "LINE_ITEMS");
    xmlNodePtr merch = find_node(items, "MERCHANDISE");
    xmlNodePtr desc  = find_node(merch, "DESCRIPTION");

    for (xmlNodePtr cur = desc->children; cur != NULL; cur = cur->next) {
        if (cur->type == XML_ENTITY_REF_NODE) {
            printf("entity ref node\n");
        }
        else {
            printf("other node of type: %d\n", cur->type);
        }
    }

    xmlFreeDoc(doc);

    return 0;
}
```

If I compile with

```
gcc -std=c99 -O2 -I/usr/include/libxml2 so.c -lxml2 -o so
```

and run it, the result is

```
entity ref node
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your help. Even i wanted entity for not to be replaced. I did not specify XML_PARSE_NOENT option as the xmlparseoption in the xmlReadMemory function. I have pasted that function call above. Still i observe that entity is getting replaced, i mean Description field is getting replaced with content of //etc/issue file exists on the system which we want to avoid. Am i missing something here??

Comment: @PraveenPVS If I run test program in my updated answer, the entity is not replaced.

Comment: Thank you, checking the node type helped to identify the node which has external reference